# I receive an error message when connecting to MySql from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I receive an error message while I'm connecting to MySql from Python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user',password='password',
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 265, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 960, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 289, in _open_connection
    self._do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 148, in _do_handshake
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1130: Host 'Owner-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Comment: Is database running?

Comment: Seems like you have permissions issues for your mysql user. Use something like GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@IP-address IDENTIFIED BY ‘root_password‘ WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: @AnkitJindal that worked. thanks much

Comment: check up your permission

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have permissions issues for your mysql user.

Use `GRANT` statement:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO root@IP-address IDENTIFIED BY 'root_password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

With your installation user (root probably), check in your mysql database, table user, if you see your Owner-PC user.
If so, check if the IP access is correct.
You should see an error on the user or the IP address (% means all IP allowed).
Then yes, grant privileges + flush privileges ... and try again to connect.